react-native-fs ignores files in PDF format
I don't understand why it reads all files from the folder except files in pdf format, what's the problem? Or am I not doing something right? Here is my code
  const readFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const path =
        Platform.OS === 'android'
          ? `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Download`
          : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath;

      console.log('Reading files from:', path);

      const files = await RNFS.readDir(path);

      const pdfFiles = files.filter(file =>
        file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith('.pdf'),
      );

      setPdfFiles(files);
      console.log('PDF Files:', pdfFiles);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reading files:', error);
      Alert.alert('Error reading files:', error.message);
    }
  };

I will be glad if someone helps)
